# Is there a way to keep a button animated while its touched and then when its released go back to normal?

Tags: android, animation, button

I can get the button to animate when it is touched but only for a set time/repeat interval. i just want a scale animation so it grows in size while touched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to animate a button when it is touched and for a set period of time...repeat...etc.

Take a look at  [Animation Section](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html)

boolean  getTransformation(long currentTime, Transformation outTransformation, float scale)
Gets the transformation to apply at a specified point in time.

void     restrictDuration(long durationMillis)
Ensure that the duration that this animation will run is not longer than durationMillis.

long     getDuration()
How long this animation should last

int  getRepeatCount()
Defines how many times the animation should repeat.

I hope this helps you out.